# How to step-through debug a PHP service in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, web-services, debugging, xdebug

I have a PHP service and calling page which I am attempting to debug in Eclipse (Xdebug).
Both are part of the same project.
I can easily set up the calling page for debug and step through the code. 
When I get to the point where the calling page calls the service (POST) it goes forward without debugging and continues stepping through the calling page.

So, what I tried to do is set up to debug on the service page then browse to the calling page in a browser - ensuring that it posts to the service page using debug querystring - It does not debug the service but instead steps through the calling page.

Eclipse is new to me and I've worked mostly with Visual Studion / WCF with services.  In that environment, I would start two instances of VS - one running the service, the other, the calling page.  When the service was invoked, the debugger would automatically step through.  I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Eclipse.

Again, the goal is to step through the service after it has had the proper test data posted to it (by any means).

Is there some other way to do this in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint in the code of the service ...

Comment: Thanks. I did that. No effect.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I've only ever used explicit debug mode and `echo` or `var_dump` to troubleshoot my PHP code. Had no idea you could actually debug it. My usual setup is either Visual Studio or NetBeans accompanied by XXAMP. I'll have to try that next time I have a PHP-centered course.